# ArangoDB: strange behavior while traversing with PRUNE

Tags: arangodb

I want to traverse a graph and check the degree of each vertex. If some vertex has the degree exceeding the threshold value it must be included in the result but traversing process must not follow that path. According to the documentation PRUNE option seems suitable for me.

I wrote the query:

```
FOR v, e IN 3 ANY 'nodes/ce07aa' GRAPH 'test_graph'
   PRUNE (FOR r IN rels FILTER r._from == v._id COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count RETURN count) + (FOR r IN rels FILTER r._to == v._id COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count RETURN count) > 100
   RETURN {name: v.name, type: v.type}
```

But it takes too much time to execute it. And there is a strange thing in the execution plan which I can't understand.

```
Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                      Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                    1   * ROOT
  8   SubqueryNode                     1     - LET #4 = ...   /* subquery */
  2   SingletonNode                    1       * ROOT
  3   EnumerateCollectionNode   37981389         - FOR r IN rels   /* full collection scan, projections: `_from` */
  4   CalculationNode           37981389           - LET #10 = (r.`_from` == v.`_id`)   /* simple expression */   /* collections used: r : rels */
  5   FilterNode                37981389           - FILTER #10
  6   CollectNode                      1           - COLLECT  WITH COUNT INTO count   /* count */
  7   ReturnNode                       1           - RETURN count
 15   SubqueryNode                     1     - LET #8 = ...   /* subquery */
  9   SingletonNode                    1       * ROOT
 10   EnumerateCollectionNode   37981389         - FOR r IN rels   /* full collection scan, projections: `_to` */
 11   CalculationNode           37981389           - LET #12 = (r.`_to` == v.`_id`)   /* simple expression */   /* collections used: r : rels */
 12   FilterNode                37981389           - FILTER #12
 13   CollectNode                      1           - COLLECT  WITH COUNT INTO count   /* count */
 14   ReturnNode                       1           - RETURN count
 16   TraversalNode                   64     - FOR v  /* vertex */ IN 3..3  /* min..maxPathDepth */ ANY 'nodes/ce07aa' /* startnode */  GRAPH 'test_graph'
 17   CalculationNode                 64       - LET #16 = { "name" : v.`name`, "type" : v.`type` }   /* simple expression */
 18   ReturnNode                      64       - RETURN #16
```

According to this it doesn't use indexes but scans full collection of edges.

However, when I try to calculate the degree and show it in the result like that:

```
FOR v, e IN ANY 'nodes/ce07aa' GRAPH 'test_graph'
   let degree = (FOR r IN rels FILTER r._from == v._id COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count RETURN count) + (FOR r IN rels FILTER r._to == v._id COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO count RETURN count)
   RETURN {name: v.name, type: v.type, degree: degree}
```

It works as I expect:

```
    Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode        1   * ROOT
  2   TraversalNode        4     - FOR v  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ ANY 'nodes/ce07aa' /* startnode */  GRAPH 'test_graph'
  9   SubqueryNode         4       - LET #4 = ...   /* subquery */
  3   SingletonNode        1         * ROOT
 20   IndexNode            2           - FOR r IN rels   /* edge index scan, scan only */    
  7   CollectNode          1             - COLLECT  WITH COUNT INTO count   /* count */
  8   ReturnNode           1             - RETURN count
 16   SubqueryNode         4       - LET #8 = ...   /* subquery */
 10   SingletonNode        1         * ROOT
 21   IndexNode            2           - FOR r IN rels   /* edge index scan, scan only */    
 14   CollectNode          1             - COLLECT  WITH COUNT INTO count   /* count */
 15   ReturnNode           1             - RETURN count
 18   CalculationNode      4       - LET #17 = { "name" : v.`name`, "type" : v.`type`, "degree" : (#4 + #8) }   /* simple expression */
 19   ReturnNode           4       - RETURN #17
```

Why does the same subquery execute in such different ways?
Is there a better approach of filtering vertexes by their degrees?

Thanks!